# Loop until a colored cell is reached

Tags: excel, vba

Example of what the progress column looks like:

[image]

I have a table with *projects* written in gray cells and *sub-projects* in non colored cells.

The progress on each sub-project is supposed to feed into an average that displays the overall progress of the entire project (e.g. 2 sub-projects, one is 75% done, the other 25%, ergo the whole project is 50% done).

I had an idea to write a scrip that builds itself a range (I can't just define a static range because there's different amounts of sub-projects for every project and sometimes new ones get added after the fact etc. etc.), by going one down and adding the values to a pool until another *gray cell* is reached and then take an average (I've tried `Do While` and `Do Until`), but I just can't make it work.

I also need the overall progress (AKA the Calculated average progress of all sub-projects under THAT specific project) to show up in the gray cells.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I first just read the heading:

```vb
While Selection.Interior.ColorIndex <> 2
    ' do stuff here
    Selection.offset(1, 0).Select
Wend
```

you can change `Selection` with any range variable depending on your approach.

Note that this will not check conditional formatting. If there are cells colored due to conditional formatting, you're better off checking the conditions directly instead.

As for the rest of the description, try this code:

```
    Dim r As Range
    Dim prev As Range
    Dim sum As Variant
    Dim count As Integer
    Set r = Cells(1, 1)
    sum = 0
    count = 0
    While r.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Or r.value <> ""
        If r.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 Then
            If Not prev Is Nothing Then
                prev.value = sum / count
            End If
            Set prev = r
            sum = 0
            count = 0
        Else
            sum = sum + r.value
            count = count + 1
        End If
        Set r = r.offset(1, 0)
    Wend
    prev.value = sum / count
```

i've assumed that the macro shall stop when it reaches a blank non-gray cell

Comment: Keep out: there are two reasons why a cell can be coloured: either it is set like this, either it is a result of conditional formatting. Does your code cover both cases?

Comment: Dominique: added note about it.

Comment: Thank you for the Reply Tom, Turns out the rest of the macro Eludes my Abilities as well, would you mind elaborating on the "Do stuff here" section?
My Research tells me to use "Application.Average("Range")" but im not sure how to integrate it into your solution or a working macro for that matter (as i technically dont have a set range right?).

Im very sorry about being a bit clueless, i have only been working with VBA for about 2 weeks. @TomNavidi

P.S. The Cells are colored due to an "add new project" makro that copies Lines from a different worksheet containing Dropdown menus ETC.

Comment: added some code that will solve the example given in your description.